# How do I get the property type from a DataGridBoundColumn

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am trying to get the column (property) type of a data bound column (data grid; SQL table) and for the life of me I can't get it to work the way I want it to.

*PLEASE NOTE* This solution is in WPF, not Windows Forms!

I have tried this with no avail:

```
       Dim s As String
    Dim value As String = tbFilter.Text.ToString()
    Try

        For Each column As DataGridBoundColumn In DG1.Columns
            If TypeOf column.Header Is String Then
                s = s + "[" + column.Header.ToString + "] LIKE '*" + value + "*' OR "
            End If
        Next
        s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 4)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

I take the string (s) and add it as a custom filter like so:

```
        If tbFilter.Text.Length > 0 Then
        Try
            view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DG1.ItemsSource)
            view.CustomFilter = s
            DG1.ItemsSource = view
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Else
        Try
            view.CustomFilter = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If
```

The error I get is:  **Cannot preform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.**

Does anyone know how I can make sure I only concatenate string column types?

Here's how I was able to achieve it by using Windows Forms:

```
        Dim s As String = ""
    Dim value As String = tbPackageFilter.Text.ToString
    Try
        For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In dgPackage.Columns
            If column.ValueType.Name = "String" Then
                s = s + "[" + column.Name.ToString + "] LIKE '*" + value + "*' OR "
            End If
        Next
        s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 4)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

In WPF I cannot use DataGridViewColumn, and the column (DataGridBoundColumn) doesn't have a property called ValueType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out:

```
        Try

        For Each col As DataColumn In mydatasetuser.Tables("MyTable").Columns

            Dim type = col.DataType
            If type.Name = "String" Then
                s = s + "[" + col.ToString + "] LIKE '*" + value + "*' OR "
            End If

        Next
        s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 4)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

So, basically instead of looking at the DG1.Columns I looked at my datasource, which was:

```
mydatasetuser.Tables("MyTable").Columns
```

So glad this is past me!

Thanks guys!